# How to implement a Like/Unlike button (or link) with value saved in DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I plan to develop a website [asp.net mvc4, C#, simplemembership and EF] where my users can create a post, and users (owner of the post or the others) could like/unlike it. At this point, I can't see how to implement this feature. I thought about many things :

First, my post class will have a boolean Like property, and then, when a user click on the like link(or button) it will save the value in my db. But in that case, I can't know which user like the post.

Second, have post class, and a like class with a postId and a userId inside. On the same principle, when a user click on the like link(or button), it will save the binary value in my db.

I think the second one is the best (maybe there is another better solution), but still, I don't know how to handle the action method of that link or button, which will display, for example "unlike" when a user like the post, and the names of users who liked it.

I don't know if i'm clear... I would like to know if you have any idea on how to do it, or link where you can send me... anything.

Comment: You need a "user likes" table with the user id and post id. When they like a post, insert a record. If they dislike a post, delete it.

Comment: Thank you, so I've created my table, and I thought about creating a method in my postController which will doing this : when I clink on the link, it retrieve the User.Identity, and the postId and insert those informations in my db. Just like you said. But I don't know how to write a method which just insert something in my db when I click the link, or delete it when I click it again. Could you give me some tips please ? If it's possible to implement something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement a controller taking the name of the user who pressed the like button. save the name and id of post in a table in the database and then when you want to find out how many likes the post has just run a select against the database.

select count(*) from likes where linkId = [value];

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table to store like events with at least a user identity and a post id. Then you can create a post view that has a count colon of likes, etc.